# Let $r$, $s$, $t$ be the roots of the equation $x^3 - 6x^2 + 5x + 1$. What is the value of $(2-r)(2-s)(2-t)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the question is mentioned in my math olympiad. please explain how to solve the problem. I have factorised the equation to $-x^2+1$, $x-6x$, $-5x +1$. I am only in year 6.Help!

Comment: @julien: It's not a duplicate, it's the same question, migrated here!

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, then. But I confess I don't understand. The same question appears twice here on MSE. One must be a duplicate, no?

Comment: @CameronBuie This is a duplicate... note that this one has 0 votes, the other has 2 votes.